# 2014 Jeep Grand Cherokee - ESC light stays on

Tags: jeep, chrysler, grand-cherokee, esp-esc

The Electronic Stability Control light is staying on in my 2014 Jeep Grand Cherokee.

I took it to a dealership and they said they fixed it by flashing some modules though it's still on. I'd take it back but they broke part of the bumper, disconnected my washer fluid reservoir, and recommended replacing the leaking reservoir for $468. I re-connected the hose, filled it with fluid, and it's fine. Because of that, I don't trust the dealership in this town.

My wife and I are driving back home in a week and I'd like to make sure everything is OK before we drive ~1200 miles.

The vehicle is driving fine. No issues felt. It's just the ESC light as far as I can tell.

I purchased an OBD2 scanner and the only code returned is
 *C2227-00 - ABS Disabled ECU: No Sub Type Information*. I haven't found much information about this error. One web page suggested it was the brake temperature sensor though it was about a Hyundai and I don't know if that's relevant.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a generic code, an OBD2 scanner isn't enough. You'd need to have someone with an Enhanced OBD2 scanner to pull any codes from the EBCM.

Wheel speed sensor codes are common. Check the mounting ring in the rears they tend to rot away leaving the sensor hanging. Check the encoder rings for damage or debris.

You could also scope the sensors. They're an active type, 12v on one wire ~1.5v or ground on the other. The sensor signal is measured in millivolts usually. When the EBCM throws a WSS DTC it will shutdown power to the sensor in question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've never heard about Enhanced OBD2. Would a Autel AL519 do the trick?

It's dark now but I'll check the sensors in the morning.

Comment: @SethMiller It looks like the 619 would be the minimum. Doesn’t look like the 519 can talk to the ebcm.